# Comparing 2 files using awk , not getting any results - C shell

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, tcsh, csh

I am using c shell and trying to compare 2 files using awk . But the below awk statement doesnt give any result.

Need to acheive this solution in awk using C shell.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]++;next} 
{
{if \!( $0 in a )
{
    print $0
} 
}' cmp1 cmp2
```

## cmp1 file

```
file:tst1
md5sum:aED567ZZZ
rowcount:1256
```

## cmp2 file

```
file:tst1
md5sum:AED567ZZZ
rowcount:1257
```

## o/p expected

```
rowcount:1257
md5sum:aED567ZZZ
```

Comment: `awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]++;next}!($0 in a)' cmp1 cmp2`

Comment: and no, there's no need to escape the `!` before `(` in `csh`.

Comment: `awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]++}!($0 in a)' cmp1 cmp2` ?

Comment: You need to escape the newlines inside a quoted string in csh.Apart from that dangling brace preceding the if clause.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot take much credit for the solution but here it is

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]++;next}
{
{if ( $0 in a == 0 )
{
    print $0
}
}}' cmp1 cmp2
```

Credit goes to @karthikr and @jeff

PS. Note that you had a missing } in your code sample.

Comment: Why do we need an additional  "}" ?

Comment: The if condition should be evaluated only when $0 is not in a (i.e.  !( $0 in a )) .        In that case will this condition work if ( $0 in a == 0 )

Answer (score 0):

Or `comm -13 cmp1 cmp2`, and you don't have any csh-related entanglements.

Comment: only if the two files are sorted

Comment: If we need to sort the files, cmp1 and cmp2 before passing to the awk command or to the comm command , what should be the working command before passing it.